# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). output when attempting to save information to database

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, xampp

I created a small program where the user must input data into text fields and select options from combo boxes. I created a database using XAMPP and created the corresponding tables for the program through the web browser.

The database is called **activitydb** and the table that's responsible for storing the data from the program is called **userdata**.

The first column in the table is called **UserID** and is an int that auto increments every time a new entry is added.
The rest are all varchars with varying maximum lengths.

This is currently the source code of the program:

```
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
try {
    // activitydb = database name
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activitydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
    st = con.createStatement();
    // userdata = table name
    String sqlconn = "INSERT INTO userdata (UserID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Email, Sex, HomeAddress, City, CPUBrand, ComputerType, HardwareSpecs, GPUBrand, GPUType, GPUVRAM)";
    PreparedStatement prdStmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlconn);
    // Input of variable data into corresponding database table
    // First table will be declared as null as it is an Integer designed with an Auto Increment
    prdStmt.setString(1, null);
    prdStmt.setString(2, jTextLastName.getText());
    prdStmt.setString(3, jTextFirstName.getText());
    prdStmt.setString(4, jTextMiddleName.getText());
    prdStmt.setString(5, jTextEmail.getText());
    prdStmt.setString(6, jComboBoxSex.getSelectedItem().toString());
    prdStmt.setString(7, jTextHomeAddress.getText());
    prdStmt.setString(8, jTextCity.getText());
    prdStmt.setString(9, jComboBoxCPUBrand.getSelectedItem().toString());
    prdStmt.setString(10, jComboBoxComputerType.getSelectedItem().toString());
    prdStmt.setString(11, jComboBoxHardwareSpecs.getSelectedItem().toString());
    prdStmt.setString(12, jComboBoxGPUBrand.getSelectedItem().toString());
    prdStmt.setString(13, jComboBoxGPUType.getSelectedItem().toString());
    prdStmt.setString(14, jComboBoxGPUVRAM.getSelectedItem().toString());
    // Do this if something goes wrong
} catch (SQLException err) {
    // Print error message to console for diagnosis
    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
}
```

For the combo boxes, I've used `getSelectedItem().toString()` to have the data found inside stored as a String.

Clicking the button will make the program do nothing but print this in the console:
`Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).`

Comment: Your sql statement does not contain any placeholders (`?`) for the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the place holders `?` to put the values, your query should be :

```
String sqlconn = "INSERT INTO userdata (UserID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName," +
        " Email, Sex, HomeAddress, City, CPUBrand, ComputerType, HardwareSpecs," +
        " GPUBrand, GPUType, GPUVRAM) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: It appears that the error no longer appears in the console after clicking the button, however, no changes are made to the database. I have restarted the MySQL server, XAMPP client, and NetBeans IDE 8.2.

Comment: @Rattle189 you have another issue, which is, you are not executing your statement, so in the end of your setting params, you have to call `prdStmt.executeUpdate();`

Comment: Adding `prdStmt.executeUpdate();` did the trick, the program now records to the database. Thank you for the help, I apologize if the question was too simple as I am a beginner to Java and only recently tackled databases.